# Execute scripts from Django server by other unix user

Tags: linux, unix, sudo

I have django server installed under ownership of user say 'X'. Now I want to switch to user 'Y' and execute some scripts. Currently for changing user I am using **sudo su "Y" -c "commands to execute"** . I have added user "X" in sudoers file so that now it does not ask for a password.

Is there any way to do it without sudo.I have already tried it by editing /etc/pam.d/su file so that it does not ask for password when user X runs "su Y" without sudo.

Is there any other way in which this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setuid bit for script, I think.

```
chmod a+u your_script_to_execute
```

will do the trick. Then any user will launch this script with priviligies of it's owner

You can read more at https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-special-permissions-the-setuid-setgid-and-sticky-bits